# SDL Web8: Soft notification for item changes

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

I want to setup the Soft notification for publication, schema, bundle, component,page,structure and folder changes in sdl web8. it`s possible to setup soft notification. any one implemented before soft notification.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do. Please add some details so that we can attempt to answer your question. It's useful to know what you want to do, what you've tried already, and what problems you experienced.

Comment: Are you referring to this: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Cloud-v1/GUID-0282D1DD-748A-49F1-B231-DB8DC89B6AC9 ? This is currently only available in Cloud, and will be included in Web 8.5 in a few weeks.

Comment: Implemented Notification sending in event system side. But I want to Implement GUI receiving. I refer given above mention, but required more information. any one have sample code?  please share it will help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Implemented the logic and solution code:

**Step1:**

> Create a SDLResponder.js

```
SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder = function SDLResponder() {
    Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "Tridion.ContentManager.SDLResponder");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.MarshallableObject");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.InitializableObject");
    this.initialize();
};

SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.IDENTIFIER = "tcm:SDLResponder";

SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.prototype._initialize = function SDLResponder$_initialize() {
    this.callBase("Tridion.InitializableObject", "_initialize");
    SDLWeb.Web.UI.Core.NotificationBroadcaster.getInstance().addEventListener("notification", this.getDelegate(this.handleNotification));
};

SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.prototype.handleNotification = function SDLResponder$handleNotification(event) {
    if (event.data !== null) {
        var id = Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User["@ID"];
        var data = event.data;
        if (data.details.userId !== null && data.details !== undefined) {

            if (data.details !== null && data.details.userId !== null && data.details.userId == id) {
                switch (data.action) {
                    case "PageSave":                       
                        //MessageCenter$registerNotification(title, description, local, modal, htmlDescription) for hyperlinks to work send true for html description
                        $messages.registerNotification("Notification", "" + data.details.messageNotification, true, null, true);
                        break;
                    case "ComponentSave":

                        //MessageCenter$registerNotification(title, description, local, modal, htmlDescription) for hyperlinks to work send true for html description
                        $messages.registerNotification("Notification", "" + data.details.messageNotification, true, null, true);
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
};

if (!$models.getFromRepository(SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.IDENTIFIER)) {
    $models.createInRepository(SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder.IDENTIFIER, "SDLWeb.ContentManager.SDLResponder");
};
```

**Step2: Added below line into editor.config:**

```
<cfg:file type="script">/Notifications/SDLResponder.js</cfg:file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Soft Notifications (based on SignalR) is a new feature of SDL Web 8.2 (Cloud Only) and will only be available on premise when 8.5 is released (December 2016).

Therefore, I suspect you will not find anyone here with experience yet. It is however pretty well documented [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Cloud-v1/GUID-0282D1DD-748A-49F1-B231-DB8DC89B6AC9).

Comment: And we can't wait for this too!

Comment: Though technically we use SignalR behind-the-scenes, as we go along describing this on Tridion Stack Exchange and in the community, we should refer to the Notification framework and Notification Broadcaster.

Comment: Implemented Notification sending in event system side. But I want to Implement GUI receiving.